# How to force Org-mode to open a link in another frame?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Org-mode it is possible to have links and top open links. As listed by http://orgmode.org/orgcard.txt in Org-mode <kbd>C-u C-c C-o</kbd> or <kbd>mouse-3</kbd> forces links to open in another window. How can I do the corresponding for frames, that is, how can I force a link to open in another frame?

What I want is for <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> to work as per default but <kbd>C-u C-c C-o</kbd> to force the link to be opened in another frame.

(For the distinction of windows and frames see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frames.html.)

I am running Org-mode 7.6 in 23.3.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested and you can get it to work by wrapping `org-open-at-point` in a `(let )` as a custom function.

In this case I'm just prefixing the current `org-link-frame-setup` with your desired `find-file-other-frame` to ensure that if you use the command on another link type it will not fail.

```lisp
(defun zin/org-open-other-frame ()
  "Jump to bookmark in another frame. See `bookmark-jump' for more."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-link-frame-setup (acons 'file 'find-file-other-frame org-link-frame-setup)))
    (org-open-at-point)))
```

I suspect you will need to bind it to a key sequence other than `C-u C-c C-o`, unless Emacs will permit you to bind it to that sequence specifically.

Comment: That works fine. Yeah, it threw an error when I tried to bind to that sequence. I used `C-c 5 C-o`. How would you proceed if you still want the original sequence? Hijack the function `C-c C-o` is bound to and tell it that when it is invoked with the universal argument it should do `zin/org-open-other-frame`?

Comment: Well if you bind it to `C-c 5 C-o` it will provide you with your `open-other-frame` functionality without having any impact on the normal `C-c C-o` sequence.  You might be able to use `defadvice` to map the universal argument to `zin/org-open-other-frame` but I know the universal argument is already used in the function.  It might be easiest to keep `C-c C-o` for `open-other-window`, `C-c 5 C-o` for `open-other-frame` and `C-u C-c C-o` for `open-with-emacs`.

Comment: Jonathan,
Your code does not work in my emacs (24.2.1), 
it says: Symbol's function definition is void: acons
Have you any idea where can I get this acons?

Comment: Oops... Sorry, found answer by myself: (acons x y z) is the same as (cons (cons x y) z)

Comment: @yashaka acons is part of `cl`.  You should be able to get it to work directly using `(require 'cl)`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the variable `org-link-frame-setup` (`M-x customize-variable RET org-link-frame-setup`). The docstring should explain the approach.

Comment: If I set the `file` bit of `org-link-frame-setup` to `find-file-other-frame` it *always* (e.g. both if I use `C-c C-o` and `C-u C-c C-o`) opens files in new frames. This is not what I want. I want it to open links in a new frame only when I force it (do `C-u C-c C-o`), otherwise I want the default behavior.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think this is possible out of the box. What you could do as some kind of quick workaround is to customize `org-file-apps` for the file types in question and enter something like `emacsclient -c %s` as app. This way, `C-c C-o` would open the file in a new frame while `C-u C-c C-o` will open it as defined in `org-link-frame-setup` (e.g. in another window). Not quite what you are looking for but maybe close enough?

Comment: Would it be possible to make it the other way around so that `C-c C-o` opens as defined in `org-link-frame-setup` but `C-u C-c C-o` opens in a new frame? The other way around would be interesting if everything else fails.

Comment: Looking through the code, I doubt there's any way to get `org-link-frame-setup` to work as desired under the current system.  Somewhere around line 9993 of `org.el` in the function `org-open-file` you get `((or (stringp cmd) (eq cmd 'emacs))` as the match for a `(cond ...)`.  `cmd 'emacs` is the value passed with `C-u C-c C-o`. This uses the customization in `org-link-frame-setup` as does the `t` case (`C-c C-o`).

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in a non-customized emacs:

```
emacs -q
GNU Emacs 24.0.92.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2011-11-30 on MARVIN
Org-mode version 7.7
```

When running `C-c C-o` and `C-u C-c C-o` on a link similar to the following:

```
file:~/Dropbox/org/test.org::*Test
```

I end up with a new frame being opened in both cases.  `C-u C-u C-c C-o` opens the `test.org` file in my active emacsclient session.  When changing the link to `.../org/test.txt` it still opens in a new frame, however it is unable to create the new file (I'm assuming I don't have .txt properly associated on my end, which is possible).

Testing with `[mailto:test@test.org][test-mail]]` also results in new frames by default.

---

Edit:  The value for `org-link-frame-setup` is as follows (it is also the default since it is from `emacs -q`):

```lisp
Its value is ((vm . vm-visit-folder-other-frame)
 (gnus . org-gnus-no-new-news)
 (file . find-file-other-window)
 (wl . wl-other-frame))
```

Comment: In your setup, what is the value of the variable `org-link-frame-setup`? I am running Org-mode 7.6 in 23.3.1.

Comment: It is strange that you get the result of opening the link in a new frame when the variable is set to `find-file-other-window`, and not `find-file-other-frame`, for `file`. It seems to me that either it is a bug or you got the window–frame distinction wrong. On my setup the variable has the same value.

Comment: @N.N. I edited in the value. It is possible that it was changed between 7.6 and 7.7.  I don't have any installation of emacs23 to be able to test it that way, but it might be that the change occurred in emacs and not in org-mode.

Comment: Oops, I thought I'd had it right (and strangely enough have had it right in the past when getting my agenda to open the way I wanted it), yet got it backwards.  Sorry about that and ignore the answer.